# Copy remote logfile over 2 hop SSH sessions, without the need for keying passwords

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, scp

I wish to get logfile from a remotePC via a gatewayServer to my local PC without keying passwords.
The gateway server used acctA@gatewayServer.
The remote PC used acctB@remotePC.

I have setup the SSH private/public keys on both gateway & remote.

From my local PC, I could SSH into remotePC directly via 2 hops without the need to key the 2 accounts' passwords, using:
   `ssh acctA@gatewayServer -t ssh acctB@remotePC`

But when I use SCP with ProxyCommand, it ask me for the password for acctB. Why?

`scp -Cp -o "ProxyCommand ssh -q acctA@gateway -W remotePC:22" acctB@remotePC:/opt/logpath/log1.tgz log01.tgz`

Advance thanks & appreciation to anyone who can advice.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing is to introduce these lines in your *.ssh/config* file:

```
  Host remotePC
  User          acctB
  HostName      remotePC
  ProxyCommand  ssh AcctA@gatewayServer nc %h %p 2> /dev/null
```

which you can then use to connect or copy files simply by means of:

```
  ssh remotePC
  scp acctB@remotePC:/home/AcctB/somefile .
```

For this to work, you nee the netcat (*nc*) command installed on the gatewayServer.

If you really insist on a one-liner (but I can never remember all this stuff), here you go:

```
ssh -o "ProxyCommand ssh acctA@gatewayServer nc -w 1 %h 22" acctB@remotePC
```

and likewise for scp.

Comment: The .ssh/config is in my local PC or at the gatewayServer?

The one-liner didn't work, it still prompt for password.

Comment: It should be on your local machine. Try starting the ssh server, on the remote machine B, as follows: *sudo service ssh stop; /usr/bin/sshd -Dd* and then try to ssh/scp into it. It will send to the screen all sorts of useful debug info. If in doubt, post it.